# Python can't fullscreen in webdriver chrome after update to v.85

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can not use fullscreen argument after chromedriver update to version 85.
I try to don't update chromedriver but it's can't run python code because Chrome browser update already.
This is my code for check.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
test = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
test.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Who know about this problem or also see this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `maximize_window()`

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
test = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
test.get('http://www.google.com')
test.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Dont know but maxmize_window acts weirdly. Sometime it maximizes window sometime it doesnt, though chrome is upated. Do you know any other method except maximize_Window() @rahul rai

Comment: Try **driver.fullscreen_window()** if maximize is not working. By the which platform you are trying window or macbook ?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thank you so much!! It's work!