# chrome driver wont stay maximised using python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chromedriver v88.0.4324.96 and 88.0.4324.27 using python will not stay maximised. My old groovy code still works with the same driver (and options) so i went and tried to manipulate these chromeoptions without success:

```
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-features=NetworkService")
    options.add_argument("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--useAutomationExtension=false")
```

I've looked at
[Python can't fullscreen in webdriver chrome after update to v.85](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716200/python-cant-fullscreen-in-webdriver-chrome-after-update-to-v-85)
but the fullscreen thing gave the same result and the `.maximize_window()` function kills the window as soon as it open :( it  seems to be a popular solution.

I also can't upgrade to the latest chrome (policies) and looking at the release notes issue 3690 might be the issue but now https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ is down...

looking at the chromedriver log i see the resize happeneing but its not from me:

```
[1614679235.268][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1614679235.268][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=144) 0C0CC2C41CA4BE07557A5F9CB5CFFFEC {
   "expression": "1"
}
[1614679235.269][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=144) 0C0CC2C41CA4BE07557A5F9CB5CFFFEC {
   "result": {
      "description": "1",
      "type": "number",
      "value": 1
   }
}
[1614679235.269][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1614679235.269][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Browser.getWindowForTarget (id=6) browser {
   "targetId": "0C0CC2C41CA4BE07557A5F9CB5CFFFEC"
}
[1614679235.269][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Browser.getWindowForTarget (id=6) browser {
   "bounds": {
      "height": 935,
      "left": 10,
      "top": 10,
      "width": 1920,
      "windowState": "normal"
   },
   "windowId": 1
}
```

Comment: It takes around 7 seconds for the browser window to resize from maximum to less than half the screen

Comment: it works fine please add screen shot or videos about the actual behavior

Comment: That is also against company policy. What i can tell you is the browser resizes the moment i use the driver.get() method.

I manually clicked around but it seems the website keeps doing this resize thing every click

Comment: does this behavior happens if you choose some other website instead ?

Comment: This happens on all websites using this framework. I see the below on the console but i'm in doubt it has anything to do with the issue at hand:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60329/devtools/browser/ebb389ca-c1f3-4032-b0d9-83a7245a437f
[41596:42600:0302/115633.109:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [11:56:33.108] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Comment: Instead of adding all arguments try adding one by one and see if the argument is causing issue , unless you share video or pic of what's happening it's not something we could help here

Comment: Better delete that link t

Comment: are you using window size some where

Comment: yes i saw the link

Comment: I'm not - the only time i set it is in chromeoptions

Comment: The issue is with your framework as all website is having this issue, so instead of using too much page object just try to do it in single page and then investigate. I think some where in your framework you are setting window size

Comment: It has to be, i agree. I'm going to go through it like you suggested and report back when i can. Thank you PDHide

Comment: well i found the culprit sitting in my screenshot method:
s = lambda x: self.driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll' + x)
            self.driver.set_window_size(s('Width'), s('Height'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was each time taking a screenshot

```
s = lambda x: self.driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll' + x) self.driver.set_window_size(s('Width'), s('Height'))
```

Basically, dont set the window position each time you take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`options.add_argument("start-maximized")` doesn't work in my case.

Instead, calling `driver.maximize_window()` works for me.